# How to restart my private chain node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have run a private chain in my computer.
I use the command

```
eth --networkid 606 --nodiscover --allow-insecure-unlock --rpc --syncmode "full" --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --datadir /root/privateNetwork/chainData console
```

After
ctrl + c
how could I restart it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have closed the network. Re-rum the same command.
If your network is running then you can connect to the console using ipc. For example : in geth client -run `geth attach <path to geth.ipc>`

Comment: Hi,I have try to Re-run the same command ,i will get a new chain,lose data.

Comment: Try running with —datadir <dirpath> option so that you know where your ipc connection point is and where your chain data is

Comment: I try this,it works ,but i lose all blocks.i think it have other problem.
thanks.